# How to get data from other database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

config.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'exampleUser1';
$db['default']['password'] = '12345678';
$db['default']['database'] = 'exampleDB1';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = TRUE;

$db['otherdb']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['otherdb']['username'] = 'exampleUser2';
$db['otherdb']['password'] = '12345678';
$db['otherdb']['database'] = 'exampleDB2';
$db['otherdb']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['otherdb']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['otherdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['otherdb']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['stricton'] = TRUE;
```

controller

```
$otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);
$this->data['student_count'] = $otherdb->professor_m->ActiveStudent_count();
```

Modal

```
function ActiveStudent_count() {
    $otherdb->from('student');
    $otherdb->join('classes', 'student.classesID = classes.classesID', 'LEFT');
    $otherdb->join('sub_courses', 'student.sub_coursesID = sub_courses.sub_coursesID', 'LEFT');
    $otherdb->join('invoice', 'student.studentID = invoice.studentID', 'LEFT');
    $otherdb->where('student.adminID',102);
    $otherdb->where('classes.status', 1);
    $otherdb->where('invoice.feetype', 'clg');
    $otherdb->where('student.status',1);
    $otherdb->where('invoice.student_position', 1);
    $otherdb->group_by('invoice.studentID');
    $adminID = $this->session->userdata("adminID");
    $usertype = $this->session->userdata("usertype");
    $loginuserID = $this->session->userdata("loginuserID"); 
    if ($usertype=='Teacher')
    {
        $otherdb->where('student.counsellor',$loginuserID);
        $otherdb->where('invoice.userID',$loginuserID);
    }
    $query  = $otherdb->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

view/index.php

```
<?php
    echo $student_count;
?>
```

In this code I have two different database on same server. Now, I am simply create another database connection in `config.php` and In my controller I am fetching data from `professor_m` modal but when I get it in my view file. Then it throw an error i.e. `Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_driver::$professor_m`. So, How can I fix it? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);` inside `function ActiveStudent_count() {` OR Inside model constructor but not in controller.

update your controller as like

```
$this->load->model("math_model","professor_m");
$this->data['student_count'] = $this->professor_m->ActiveStudent_count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code in controller to call the model:

```
$data['student_count'] = $this->professor_m->ActiveStudent_count();
```

and do this code in `professor_m` model `ActiveStudent_count()` method:

```
$this->otherdb = $this->load->database('exampleDB2', TRUE);

$this->otherdb->query() // just put your query here like what you want
```

Hope that is work for you